# How do I get my old database back?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wampserver

Yesterday i installed xampp in my local server. Now what i have both wamp ( c drive) and xampp(g drive) in my local PC.
while installing xampp mysql was not working so i had to uninstall mysql from my local server which was with the password 'abcd'.

Now both wamp and xampp i can run easily but i can not able to see my old wamp (phpmyadmin) database that i have created while i was working with wamp.
Now i want to see those databases when i connect to wamp localhost.
Is there any way to see those databases.

Thanks

Comment: Have you started the mysql console and verfified that the databases still exists?

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi actually i was working with wamp but now my senior want xampp too now he want me to work with xampp thats why. i am opening one at a single time.

Comment: @Albin, can you explain , how i can check this using my phpmyadmin, as i told you i uninstall my mysql local server from system.

Comment: it means your senior is still noob .. so dont listen to him , technically both are wamp and xamp

Comment: Start cmd, write `mysql -u root`, (maybe enter password), run command `show databases;`

Comment: @Albin giving error may be coz i have uninstall the mysql from local server and using the phphmyadmin's mysql

Comment: So you have no mysql installed on your local machine? I think you need to install that then make a dump from that. Then you can import that file...

Comment: As both WAMPServer and XAMPP install basically the same things i.e Apache/MySQL & PHP, please specifiy WHICH MYSQL you uninstalled????